# Network interface configuration

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, tunnel

I understand (kind of) the way this file works in etc/network/interfaces.

My question is, is this the right way to think? I want to set up a static IP address, so that whenever I start up my Ubuntu server (hosted on a raspberry pi), there is a static inet address. So in my etc/network/interfaces file, I will write:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 168.68.33.33
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway ???
network 168.68.0.0   (?)
```

This will set up a static inet interface under device eth0. This will allow me to connect to my laptop by connecting an Ethernet cable from my laptop to the raspberry pi, using ‘ssh ubuntu@168.68.33.33’

Is this how the interfaces configuration file is used? After I edit the file, how do I reset the network for the changes to be applied?

Comment: The file /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated in recent Ubuntu versions. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsb_release -a` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu, Descriptor: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Release: 18.04, Codename: bionic